# Transformations of random variable: How does $|g’(g^{-1}(y))|$ become $1 \over |{dy \over dx}| $?

Tags: random-variables

In transformation of random variable: $dy \over dx$ = $g’(x)$. Why?

In a homework I found in an older website of my university, I see that they mention that:

For r.v. $Y=g(X)$:

$f_Y(y)={\Sigma f_X(g^{-1}(y)) \over |g’(g^{-1}(y))|}$

Now on [this](https://stats.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Probability_Theory/Book%3A_Probability_Mathematical_Statistics_and_Stochastic_Processes_(Siegrist)/03%3A_Distributions/3.07%3A_Transformations_of_Random_Variables) website, where the transformation is monotonous and $Y=g(X)$ has always one solution, they write it as:

${f_X|det({dx \over dy})|}$

My question is:
According to what theorem, or material that I’m yet not familiar with, did $|g’(g^{-1}(y))|$ become $1 \over |{dy \over dx}| $ ?

Comment: That looks like the derivative of the inverse function's theorem...

Comment: Thanks! Checking.

Comment: I’ll need someone to elaborate if possible, I see that the theorem talk about multiple variables. And I’m pretty weak here.

Comment: I see this for example: https://youtu.be/gS0TYC78lnw But what does dx/dy even mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inverse function theorem (in one variable) says something like: if $f(x) = y$ and $g = f^{-1}$ then

$$ g'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)}. $$

You can check this by implicitly differentiating $g(f(x)) = x$ to get $g'(f(x))f'(x) = 1$ and we said that $f(x) = y$ so this is $g'(y)f'(x) = 1$.

To put it in a different notation: if where we had $y$ as a function of $x$, we now are writing $x = g(y)$ as a function of $y$, then

$$ \frac{dx}{dy} = \frac{dg(y)}{dy} = \frac{1}{\frac{df(x)}{dx}} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}. $$

So if you like:

$$ g'(g^{-1}(x)) = g'(f(x)) = g'(y) = \frac{1}{f'(x)} = \frac{1}{\frac{dy}{dx}}. $$

Comment: Oh so $dy \over dx=f’(x)$ cool! Many many thanks!!!!